# Nav bar on top of other content CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have a navbar and after that the content of the page.

I'm trying to add shadow to the bottom of the navbar, but when I do so, you can't see the shadow because the content after the navbar is "on top" of the shadow.

I can see the shadow only if I don't insert any background color to the content after the navbar.

Also, I tried to keep the navbar always at the top of the screen when you scroll the page with `position: fixed`. And it worked in the sense that the position of the navbar was at the begging of the page always, but if I scrolled the content went over the navbar and not the opposite.

So in short, I feel like the content is "on top" of the navbar, whereas it should be the opposite.

Basically, I want the toolbar's shadow to be on top of the body content.

```css
.toolbar {
  height: 67px;
  background-color: #303031;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -2px rgba(0,0,0,3);
}

.body{
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c8ccd1  , #808080);
  height:550px;
  width:24vw;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.array-container {
  height: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 355px;
}
```

```html
<div className="page">
            <div className="toolbar">
             ///some code///
            </div>
            <div className="body">
              <div className="box">
              /// some code/// 
              </div>
              <div className="array-container">
              /// some code ///
              </div> 
            </div> 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index: 2;` to the toolbar.

Check below code.

```css
.toolbar {
  height: 67px;
  background-color: #303031;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -2px rgba(0,0,0,3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.body{
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c8ccd1  , #808080);
  height:550px;
  width:24vw;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.array-container {
  height: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 355px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
        <div class="toolbar">
         ///some code///
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <div class="box">
          /// some code/// 
          </div>
          <div class="array-container">
          /// some code ///
          </div> 
        </div> 
 </div>
```